# Correct reasoning?

Tags: meaning

> "Figures from the English Housing Survey found that just 45 percent of
>   under-45s own their own home - a fall of almost 20 percentage points
>   since 2003-4."

**From this can one reason that the percentage of people with a house in 2003-4 was greater than 65% or less than 65%?**

Basically what I am asking. is does 'almost' imply the value was less than the stated value or is it a synonym of approximately in that one can't tell if the actual value was above or greater than that stated?

Comment: Almost means close but not quite. So 45% + "almost" 20 percentage points = "almost" 65% (so strictly less than 65%).

Comment: I'm still not convinced, because 'close but not quite' does not necessarily mean less than.

Comment: It does when paired with the directionality embedded in the word "fall".

Comment: But surely a fall of 21% could be regarded as an almost 20% fall?

Comment: Sure, just as a loss of $21 could be regarded as "a loss of almost $20" -- but no one would phrase it that way. You'd say "more than $20" to emphasize it, when making a point about the loss. You would say "almost" when the value was *less* than $20 (in the case of a loss), like $19 or $18.75 or whatever.

Comment: So effectively saying a loss of almost £20.00 rather than a loss of less than £20.00 reduces the significance of the loss much less?

Comment: I agree with Dan Bron's [initial position](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340537/correct-reasoning#comment784231_340537) on this - for example, if you say that your age is "almost 20", it means that you haven't reached your 20th birthday. So a fall of "almost 20 percentage points" is a fall of less than (but close to) 20 percentage points.

Comment: Using *almost* allows you to exaggerate the size of the loss a little bit while still remaining credible.  Saying “a loss of less than twenty dollars” is downplaying the size of the loss in effect claiming it to be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

> Almost here is synonymous with less than.

If it had fallen by 10 points, then in 2003-2004 it would have been 55% (45+10).

If it had fallen by 20 points, then in 2003-2004 it would have been 65% (45+20).

But it has fallen by less than 20 points so it must have been less than 65% in 2003-2004.